# how to avoid parameter type warning for self referencing typesafe interface in java?

Tags: java, generics, tree

I am working with tree's in java and I have the following interface for a simple unordered tree with a self reference:

```
public interface Node<N extends Node> {

  public N getParent();
  public void setParent(N parent);

  public Collection<N> getChildren();

  public void addChild(N node);
  public void removeChild(N node);

  public N getRootNode();

  ... more ...
}
```

The idea of course is to create a typesafe Node

```
  public abstract class ParentChildNode<E extends Node> implements Node<E> {
```

problem that really annoys me is the warning i get:

```
ParentChild is a raw type. References to generic type Node<N> should be parameterized

warning on this line:

public interface Node<N extends Node> {

warning on this line:

    public abstract class ParentChildNode<E extends ParentChild> implements ParentChild<E>
```

I can do:

```
public interface Node<N extends Node<?>> {
```

but i fear im treading into **yuckness** territory.  i can suppress the warning but thats not allowed where i work.

any suggestions?  I noticed java.util collections API does not have any warnings anywhere.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about something like this (paralleling the declaration of the `Enum` class):

```
public interface Node<N extends Node<N>> {

  public N getParent();
  public void setParent(N parent);

  public Collection<N> getChildren();

  public void addChild(N node);
  public void removeChild(N node);

  public N getRootNode();

  ... more ...
}

public abstract class ParentChildNode implements Node<ParentChildNode> {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type is infinitely recursive. All of your nodes are really of type `Node<Node<Node<Node<…>>>>` or some equally infinite subtype. Java's generics are simply not sufficiently powerful to handle such things.

Moreover, if you have a tree of these nodes, what's the type of the root? It doesn't have a parent. I suppose you could have a type `NullNode<GodKnowsWhat>`, but that's merely putting off the problem. I suppose the root could simply return `null` as a parent, but that's subverting the whole hierarchy.

<strike>What you could have instead:</strike> I got this far:

```
public interface Node {
    public Collection<ChildNode<Node>> getChildren();

    public void addChild(ChildNode<Node> node);
    public void removeChild(ChildNode<Node> node);
}

public interface ChildNode<Parent> extends Node {
    public Parent getParent();
    public void setParent(Parent parent);
}
```

But the type of `Node`'s methods are wrong. You just can't do this in Java. If you'd really like to, try Scala. It runs on the JVM and it's type system is far more sophisticated; I'm fairly certain that it would allow the kind of type recursion you'd need. In addition, you *may* be able to pull it off in C++. C++ also has a far more powerful type system, but I haven't worked with it enough to know whether it will let you do this kind of thing in more or less these terms.